# How to disable the creation of new GitLab repositories on push?

Tags: gitlab, git-push

In [10.5](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/26388), GitLab added support to create projects (repositories) [by pushing](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/working_with_projects.html#create-a-new-project-with-git-push) into a namespace (a.h.a group). I would like to disable that feature for my whole instance, but I can't find where to do it. There also no documentation about a disable switch.

How to disable the creation of new repositories on push?

---

**Background:**
I moved a repository to another namespace, but a cloned version on some random PC is sometimes pushing to the old repository URL. Because it was moved, the developer gets no error message or warning, but he create a new repository on the server.

I found the developer and his PC and we changed the repository URL, but I still would like ti disable this feature for the future.

**Linked Issues:**

- [Add group setting to allow or disallow "Push to create project"](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/23792)
- [How to Disable Push Create for Everyone But the Admin API](https://forum.gitlab.com/t/how-to-disable-push-create-for-everyone-but-the-admin-api/42442)

Comment: Did you find a viable solution ? thanks

Comment: I'm sure it's now somehow disabled on my instance. But I'm sorry I don't remember how I did it. It was either via `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb` config file or via Ruby rails console `sudo gitlab-rails console`.